# Spring Debug logs getting printed, however i am setting log level to info

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, log4j

I have set up the log to "info" level in my application via log4j.xml.
But still, when the application getting loaded, i could see the logs of debug level.
Here is my log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration APP_DEBUG="false">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="monitoringApp" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/monitor.log" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${catalina.base}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}_monitor.gz" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p | %d{ISO8601} | [%t][%x] | %c:%L | %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="monitoringApp" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" /> -->
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

And Here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bng</groupId>
  <artifactId>monitor</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0</version>
  <name>monitor Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <springsecurity.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <commons.fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons.fileupload.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
        <springsocial.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</springsocial.version> 
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- EXCEL -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>monitor</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

And here is the console.log

> INFO | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,072 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:273 | Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,178 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:112 | Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,180 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:107 | Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,181 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:107 | Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,185 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:107 | Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,186 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:107 | Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,188 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:107 | Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,189 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:116 | Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
>    INFO | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,190 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext:510 | Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Nov 28 16:42:18 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,195 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment:172 | Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,258 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment:112 | Initializing new StandardEnvironment
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,259 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment:107 | Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,259 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment:107 | Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   DEBUG | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,259 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment:116 | Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
>    INFO | 2016-11-28 16:42:18,269 | [localhost-startStop-1][] | org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]

Can anybody please help me out? I have tried all the solutions as described on stack overflow.

Comment: where is your log4j.xml is placed?

Comment: Its in java/main/resources

Comment: what happens if you remove <priority ...> and replace <level value="INFO" />

Comment: I just want to give priority to INFO level. So did not want to remove the priority tag.